# Enable MySQL logging

Tags: mysql

Is there anyway I can log all incoming commands to my MySQL5 server?

I'm only really interested in INSERT commands, but if it's easier to log everything that's fine, I can parse out the ones I need.

Thanks

Comment: Look into the binary log

Answer (score 0):

Its an option in my.cnf whatever systems you're useing.
There are a couple ways to do it - you really have to see the documentation
[mysql doc]http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Becareful with this option - it will create big logs quick depending on your situation